# XMLhttprequest vs. opening the page?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to know is xmlhttprequest vs just opening a website any different? Before with phantomjs, I would open a page and search for an element and if it was not there I would reload the page again, I would do this without a timeout so I would get IP ban I added an interval. So my question is for xmlhttprequest, is it any different, would the website's server treat it as the same and I would get IP ban if I call the response without any constraint?

Comment: Yup, I'm afraid so...

Comment: So I will have to add an interval to xmlhttprequest as well?

Comment: AFIK Yes, because just like visiting a site, `XMLhttpRequest` makes a http request ( Nah, really! ;) ), which would be of little difference, if any,  as far as the server is concerned.

Comment: A whole page may contain multiple resources that all need to be loaded, while an XHR makes only a single request.